# Downloading HTML Entities guide on TextWrangler for Mac

Tags: mac, html, bbedit

TextWrangler for Mac does not have an HTML Entities palette built in to easily put  special characters and symbols into your code. Is there a way to download one and integrate it into the program?

Comment: If you are composing html, better to use the actual characters with utf8 encoding instead of the enttities intended for old ascii only apps

Answer (score 1):

TextWrangler is a sunsetted product. Bare Bones software no longer updates it or supports it.

You might want to look into [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), the grandfather of Mac code editors. BBEdit has a free mode where certain features are not available. I've been using it since the "Classic Mac OS" days so I am not sure what the pulled features are in the free version. But BBEdit does have exactly what you are looking for, it's a fabulous bit of Mac code. What other app can get away with the tag line "it doesn't suck?!"

(Note, I have no financial -or otherwise- interest in Bare Bones Software, just a happy customer.)